# Can message driven bean pickup message from mainframe queue?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mainframe, websphere-6.1

In our Java EE application, we were using middleware queues. From that queue, we will pick up a message and we will do processing.

Now, our client is going to put a message in a mainframe queue. Is it possible to pick up the message from that mainframe queue? Do we need to configure anything from our side of the code to pick it up?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how they set the queue up.  If your using MQ, it needs to forward messages to your queue if they are using separate queue managers.

Assuming it was done correctly, you shouldn't need to do much.  At most, subscribe to another queue.

Comment: Thanks Mike, so can't i take directly from mainframe queue. Some queue manager needs to take that message from mainframe to our queue for my use?

Comment: You can attach directly to the MF queue, you may need to install another layered product though.  It's an IBM tax, they seem to do it for everything.  I haven't touched MQ in a while, but they used to have a product called CAF (Client Attachment Feature) that you needed to buy/install.  Once you did that, you could attach through the MQ API's or through JMS??? I thought they had native support for it, but you need to check.